# Find the sequence defined by the recurrence equation $x_{n+1} = 4x_n − x_{n−1}, (n ≥ 1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, characteristic-functions

Find the sequence defined by the recurrence equation $x_{n+1} = 4x_n − x_{n−1}, (n ≥ 1)$ with $x_0 = 1$ and $x_1=2$. Find an odd prime factor of $x_{2015}$.

I've found the characteristic equation to be $x^2-4x+1=0$ and the solutions for it to be $x=2+\sqrt3$ and $x=2-\sqrt3$. I've also found 2015 to equal the product of the odd primes $5*13*31$, but don't know what to do with that, or if its relevant to being with.

What is it that I'm supposed to do next?

Comment: You might consider the sequence modulo the first few odd primes; the sequence modulo any prime (in fact, any number) is periodic - can you see why? - so start by studying which values of $x_n$ are divisible by the first few primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the question the associated quadratic is $x^2-4x+1=0$ with roots $x=2\pm\sqrt3$, so the general solution to the recurrence is $x_n=A(2+\sqrt3)^n+B(2-\sqrt3)^n$. Putting $x_0=1,x_1=2$ we get $A=B=\frac{1}{2}$.

In particular $x_{2015}=\frac{1}{2}\left((2+\sqrt3)^{2015}+(2-\sqrt3)^{2015}\right)$, which we can also write as the nearest integer to $\frac{1}{2}(2+\sqrt3)^{2015}$.

$x_{2015}$ is clearly far too large to factorise directly, but we often find that recurrence sequences are periodic modulo a prime, so we look at the first few terms: $x_1=2,x_2=7,x_3=26,x_4=97$, $x_5=362$.

If we now look at residues mod 7 we find they are 0 for $n=2\bmod 4$. That does not help. If we look at residues mod 13 we find they are 0 for $n=3\bmod 6$. Again that does not help. But the pattern of 0 for $n=k\mod 2k$ suggests that we might get lucky with $x_5$ and find that the residues mod 181 are 0 for $n=5\bmod 10$. Indeed that is the case: the first few residues are: $2, 7, 26, 97, 0, 84, 155, 174, 179, 180, 179, 174, 155, 84, 0$.

So we conclude that 181 is a factor of $x_{2015}$.

Answer (score 0):

if $u$ and $v$ are the roots of the characteristic equation, the generating function is of the form $c_1u^n +c_2v^n$. Use $x_0$ and $x_1$ to determine $c_1$ and $c_2$.